# Use environment variable / HOME for loading puttykeyfile

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I am using two different computers which access a git repository that is in a common network path. I am authenticating via pageant / TortoiseGitplink. My SSH private key is saved under `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\private.ppk`.

At the moment, each time I switch computers, I need to re-set the puttykeyfile to the other users home directory. I want to automatically load the puttykeyfile from the HOME directory on both machines.

I already tried to set up an environment variable on each machine with `HOME=c:\users\userX` and added `puttykeyfile = $HOME\\private.ppk` or `puttykeyfile = %HOME%\\private.ppk` to the `.git\config`, however, each time I get `Unable to open File` from Pageant.
If I run `pageant %HOME%\private.ppk` from the command line it works like a charm!

[image]

How can I make TortoiseGitPLink find the `private.ppk` automatically within the home dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseGit does not support environment variables for the putty key values (as of 2.11.0).

Possible workarounds could be

- to define the puttykey in the global git config (which resides in `%HOME%\.gitconfig`),
- define a default key in a PuTTY session (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html) or
- use the putty agent to load a key e.g. on startup of the computer.

Comment: After a bit of fiddling I did it with this command: `git config --global remote.origin.puttykeyfile c:\users\skjerns\private.ppk`. This works now, but only if the remote is named `origin` - any way to make it apply to all remotes? Adding it to `user` had no effect.

Comment: To make it apply to all remotes you should consider to configure the putty key as a default key in putty (e.g., for the default session).